# Load Image One By One with Jquery for Instagram API

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, instagram

I'm using Jquery to pull images from Instagram API based on hashtag and dynamically add each image one by one in a wrapper, but it all loads altogether.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/sometag/media/recent?client_id=xxxxxxx",
    success: function(response) {
  $.each(response.data, function() {

         $('#target').append($('<div><ul><li> <a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + this.images.thumbnail.url + '" /></a></li><li>Likes:' + this.likes.count + '</li></ul></div>' ).hide().fadeIn(5000));

//Tried this as well
         //$('<div><ul><li> <a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + this.images.thumbnail.url + '" /></a></li><li>Likes:' + this.likes.count + '</li></ul></div>' ).appendTo('#target').hide().fadeIn(5000);

})
}

});

</script>
</head>
   <body>

   <div id="target"></div>

   <div>test</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I want it to be similar to Lexical Gap: http://lasvegas-now.jit.su/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the transition is so fast that you can not see the images loading one by one. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I tried `$('my_html_code').hide().delay(1000).appendTo('#target').show();` but it's still not working